# Como criar uma Function que calcular o CRC16 no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, funções, checksum

sabem me dizer se existe alguma função em sql que calcule CRC16, o método de calculo é elencado como "CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF)".

CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) -> polinômio: x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + 1

tentei criar a função abaixo, mas não está calculando da maneira correta:

```
(
    @input varchar(max)
)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @crc        bigint = 0xffff
    ,       @result     int
    ;
    SELECT @crc = dbo.CRC16calc(@crc, Ascii(Substring(@input, v.id, 1)))
    FROM    dbo.IndexTable(1, LEN(@input)) AS v
    ORDER
    BY      v.Id
    ;
    SET @result = (CONVERT(int, CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), ~@crc))) ;
    RETURN @result ;
END
```

Comment: Só para confirmar o resultado esperado ... se você informar a string "123456789", o resultado esperado é o número inteiro 10673 ? ( ou seja, "0x29B1" em hexadecimal ) ?

Comment: não sei Gabriel, isso é uma opinião mas, não seria mais fácil fazer isso numa linguagem em .net, que deve muitos exemplos e código pronto, instalar a dll no server e importar a function? o código `sql` não foi feito bem pra essas coisas, é como querer programar um jogo de alta performace em `cobol`, não é bem pra isso que a linguagem foi feita. Eu já tive código assim com algoritmos de criptografia nas versões mais antigas do sql, e funcionou bem um código em .net importado como uma *function*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei exatamente a função que você procura, mas o fonte está em C -- Precisa "apenas" converter para funções do MSSQL ... Espero que lhe seja útil.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23726131/4877541

Existem outras formas de se fazer isso ... caso seja viável, você pode criar uma DLL com a função de CRC, e fazer o Bind para chamar a função da DLL de dentro de uma instrução SQL e/ou uma Stored Procedure, mais detalhes no link abaixo:

https://dbtut.com/index.php/2019/05/05/what-is-clr-and-how-to-import-dll-in-sql-server/